# Copy data to another worksheet

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have the following but it takes long time to run, it is a simple wherein the user select a file and data from Sheet1 is copied to another workbook.

```
Sub ImportApp(ByVal filepath_Report As String, file_name1 As String, wsOutput As Worksheet)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbReport = Workbooks.Open(file_name1)
    Set wsReport = wbReport.Sheets(1)
    Select Case wsOutput.Name
        Case Is = "Downtilt Tracker"
            wsReport.Activate
            With Rows(1)
                Set d = .Find("Completed Date")
                If d Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Invalid Down-Tilt Tracker." & vbNewLine & "Please import a valid Down-Tilt Tracker."
                    wbReport.Close False
                    Sheets("Control").Activate
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End With
    End Select

    wsReport.Activate: wsReport.Cells.Copy: wsOutput.Activate: Cells(1, 1).Select: ActiveSheet.Paste: Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit: wsOutput.Range("A1:AB" & 1048576).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    wsOutput.Cells(1, 1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wbReport.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Define "a long time". 10 seconds? A few minutes? How large are the files that you're opening?

Comment: 3 Min, the file size is about 3Mbps with formatting

Comment: Just by chance, would the source workbook happen to be stored on a network drive?

Comment: no on local drive.

Comment: Linked data sources then? Lots of formulas? I find it difficult to believe this code is running that long. Step through the code line by line and see which one seems to "freeze" it for a while.

Comment: Its the line where I paste in the data "ActiveSheet.Paste"

Comment: How much data are we talking about? How does the time compare to manually copying and pasting?

Comment: The exact size of the file is 2.4 Mb and it has 4 tabs. I need data only from one of the tabs. The data is spread with 2074 rows and 27 Column. Doing it manually is pretty fast. I am not storing in the clipboard as well to be faster but still I don't understand. It probably has to do with the formatting in the sheet as I am using the same code to import workbooks withing few secs. Do you have same ideas to copy and paste data without any formatting?

Comment: Yeah. No time to review right this second, but I would definitely take a look at accessing the data via ADODB and pasting it via the [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx) method. No formatting and you don't even have to "open" the source workbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First things first - your code has some readability issues due to the
  use of the colon operator:

  ```
  wsReport.Activate: wsReport.Cells.Copy: wsOutput.Activate: Cells(1, 1).Select: ActiveSheet.Paste: Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit: wsOutput.Range("A1:AB" & 1048576).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  ```

  This makes it incredibly difficult to tell at a glance what the code
  is doing - reading down in a lot easier than reading left to right
  when you are trying to work through a sequence.  This is much, much
  better:

  ```
  wsReport.Activate
  wsReport.Cells.Copy
  wsOutput.Activate
  Cells(1, 1).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  wsOutput.Range("A1:AB" & 1048576).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  ```
- Second, you have an unused variable in the Sub declaration -
  filepath_Report is never used.  I'd remove it.
- Speaking of your Sub declaration, it looks like the intent is to pass
  all of the parameters by value, but in fact only the first parameter
  is passed by value - **ByRef** is the default and *each parameter* needs
  the **ByVal** modifier to override the default.  The code below
  demonstrates:

  ```
  Private Sub ByValDemo()

     Dim one As String, two As String

     one = "Variable one set in ByValDemo"
     two = "Variable two set in ByValDemo"
     Call IsThisByVal(one, two)
     Debug.Print one
     Debug.Print two

  End Sub

  Private Sub IsThisByVal(ByVal one As String, two As String)

     one = "Variable one set in IsThisByVal"
     two = "Variable two set in IsThisByVal"

  End Sub
  ```

  Debug output of running ByValDemo is:

  > Variable one set in ByValDemo 
  >  Variable two set in IsThisByVal

  To declare both strings as **ByVal** (the Worksheet has to be ByRef), you
  need to do this:

  ```
  Sub ImportApp(ByVal filepath_Report As String, ByVal file_name1 As String, wsOutput As Worksheet)
  ```
- The **Select**...**Case** structure is confusing as you only have one Case. A
  simple **If**...**Then** would suffice.
- Although it probably isn't effecting anything, turning off screen
  updates and then only turning it back on if your conditional executes
  probably isn't the best way to handle it. Excel *should* turn it back
  on for you when the Sub exits, but I wouldn't rely on that.
- Per your comment, it seems like you are under the impression that you
  aren't using the Windows Clipboard. This isn't accurate.  The call to
  wsReport.Cells.Copy puts *the entire Worksheet* on the clipboard. The
  .Cells property contains every possible cell in the worksheet (even 
  unused). You can confirm this by running the following, opening Notepad 
  and hitting Ctrl-V:

  ```
  Private Sub CanIHazClipboard()

      Dim sheet As Worksheet

      Set sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
      sheet.Cells.Copy
      'Prints 16384, regardless of what is being used.
      Debug.Print sheet.Cells.Columns.count
      'This would actually overflow the return variable...
      'Debug.Print sheet.Cells.Rows.Count

  End Sub
  ```
- The Application methods such as **.Select**, **.Activate**,
  **.Copy**, and **.Paste** functions are really slow compared to using the objects that you already got references to.  Use the Range
  properties instead:

  ```
  Dim target As Range
  'Set the "paste" range to the same cells as the source (needs to be the same size).
  Set target = wsOutput.Range(wsReport.UsedRange.Address)
  'If you need formulas...
  target.Formula = wsReport.UsedRange.Formula
  '...or if you only need to copy values.
  target.Value2 = wsReport.UsedRange.Value2
  ```

  This is not only incredibly faster, it doesn't trash the clipboard and you 
  don't need to keep track of what is "activated".
- You have an **Exit Sub** buried deep in a nested structure.  My personal
  rule is that if I'm going to bail out of a routine early, that
  shouldn't happen at more than one level of indentation.  I would
  personally structure the flow control in this case so that it always
  reaches the bottom of the Sub so you Don't Repeat Yourself with your
  clean-up code (I also try to avoid the **.Find** method):

  ```
  Dim found As Boolean, cell As Range

  If Not wsOutput.Name = "Downtilt Tracker" Then
      'I would assume this should also be an error condition...
  Else
      For Each cell In wsOutput.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
          If cell.Value2 = "Completed Date" Then
              found = True
              Exit For
          End If
      Next cell

      If found Then
          'Do your copy
      Else
          'Signal your error condition.
          MsgBox "Invalid Down-Tilt Tracker." & vbNewLine & _
                 "Please import a valid Down-Tilt Tracker."
      End If
  End If

  'Only need the clean-up code once.
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  wbReport.Close False
  ```

Answer (score 4):

I like your indentation. It's nice to see well-indented VBA code, it needs to be pointed out!

> ```
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> ```

That's generally a good idea, but all by itself, it makes a poor UX - and if calculation mode remains `xlAutomatic`, it might be a missed opportunity to gain some more performance by turning off calculations while you're working on the worksheet.

Thing is, that's a whole concern all by itself, and as such it deserves its own function. Almost all my macro-enabled Excel workbooks have this function somewhere:

```
Private Sub ToggleWaitMode(Optional ByVal wait As Boolean = True)
    With Excel.Application

        .Calculation = IIf(wait, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .Cursor = IIf(wait, xlWait, xlDefault)
        .StatusBar = IIf(wait, "Please wait...", False)

        .DisplayAlerts = Not wait
        .ScreenUpdating = Not wait

    End With

End Sub
```

So instead of `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, you can say `ToggleWaitMode`, and then do `ToggleWaitMode False` when you're done processing.

The problem with turning `ScreenUpdating` off, is that if anything goes wrong, it stays off and the user (and sometimes even the dev) is left thinking Excel is frozen: whenever you play with `ScreenUpdating`, you **must** handle runtime errors:

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    'do something

    CleanExit:
        'clean up code
        ToggleWaitMode False
        Exit Sub
    CleanFail:
        'error-handling code
        Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

This way you're always sure that all exit paths involve resetting `ScreenUpdating` and calculation mode.

...which is a good idea, because the next line can actually blow up whenever a bad `file_name1` is passed to the procedure:

```
Set wbReport = Workbooks.Open(file_name1)
```

---

> ```
> Set wsReport = wbReport.Sheets(1)
> ```

I like that: by assigning an object reference, you can work against that object. There are a few issues:

- Where's the declaration? **Always use `Option Explicit`** and declare all variables! If the variable is declared at module level, then the declaration belongs inside the procedure's scope - move it there, to the smallest possible scope.
- The `Sheets` collection contains chart sheets and actual worksheets. You probably intend to query the `Worksheets` collection here; if you had declared the `wsReport` variable `As Worksheet` and the `Sheets(1)` object were actually a chart sheet, you'd have a runtime error here.

> ```
> Select Case wsOutput.Name
>     Case Is = "Downtilt Tracker"
> ```

Several things here:

- You're clearly using the wrong construct here - this should definitely be an `If...Then` block; what's wrong with this?

  ```
  If wsOutput.Name = "Downtilt Tracker" Then
      '...
  End If
  ```
- I'm actually surprised `Case Is = "string literal"` actually compiles *and* works as intended; it's a pretty convoluted way of doing `Case "string literal"`...

---

And then things get a bit out of hand:

```
        wsReport.Activate
        With Rows(1)
            Set d = .Find("Completed Date")
            If d Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Invalid Down-Tilt Tracker." & vbNewLine & "Please import a valid Down-Tilt Tracker."
                wbReport.Close False
                Sheets("Control").Activate
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
```

- You have a reference to the `wsReport` object - you don't need to `.Activate` it.
- The `With` block adds unnecessary indentation and confusion. I'd do `wsReport.Rows(1).Find` instead.
- `d` is a meaningless name that doesn't tell anything about what you're doing here.
- You need a reference to the `"Control"` sheet. Declare and assign another `Worksheet` variable, and *use it* instead of `Select`ing and `Activate`ing and using implicit-context `Cells`.
- If `d` isn't `Nothing`, you don't appear to be setting `ScreenUpdating` back to `True`. The control flow described in my introduction would solve that.

Avoid this - **AT ALL COSTS**:

> ```
> wsReport.Activate: wsReport.Cells.Copy: wsOutput.Activate: Cells(1, 1).Select: ActiveSheet.Paste: Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit: wsOutput.Range("A1:AB" & 1048576).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
> ```

There are **7 instructions** on that line of code; there's no reason to do this. Ever.

And here's where I'd think your bottleneck is:

> ```
> wsReport.Cells.Copy
> ```

You're copying the entire worksheet.

> ```
> wsOutput.Range("A1:AB" & 1048576)
> ```

Why bother with the concatenation here? It's hard-coded anyway, and besides, `A1` has its row specified inside the string literal.

```
wsOutput.Range("A1:AB1048576")
```

This might work a bit better - if not, it's at least certainly much easier to read:

```
wsReport.UsedRange.Copy
wsOutput.Range("A1").Paste
wsOutput.UsedRange.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
wsOutput.UsedRange.HoriontalAlignment = xlCenter
```

Comment: I totally missed the `Is = "String"` syntax.  I actually had to test it to see if it worked (which it does).  Then I remembered that `Is` really isn't an operator like VB.NET - it's freaky VBA syntax for boolean Case conditionals.  VBA inserts it automatically if you put an `=` after `Case`. I'm guessing it's to support the equally weird `Select Case True` syntax (that I shamefully admit to using sometimes).

Comment: It blew my mind too @Comintern. The examples I saw when I looked it up used it to find ranges (that would be better as `if`s IMO). `Case Is < 100` and such.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was successfully able to bring down the run time from 3 mins to 1 min...